# Why is mr Github repository link not working?

Tags: html, github, repository

I have uploaded my html file in github repository but the repository link is not working. It just shows the name of my repository when the link is clicked. PS: I am a beginner. I have just started learning html.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ9kX.jpg) please explain me in simple language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have set the visibility of the repository to private or restricted. So when you click the link it will not show the repository with all the files. My suggestion is that you follow Github's instructions for making it public and try the link again. `https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/setting-repository-visibility`. If that does not work make sure that you have copied the right link for the home view. Hope this help and good luck with your HTML adventures!